# Prove $x^{n}-5x+7=0$ has no rational roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

This question arises in STEP 2011 Paper III, question 2. The paper can be found [here](http://www.admissionstestingservice.org/our-services/subject-specific/step/preparing-for-step/).

The first part of the question requires us to prove the result that if the polynomial
$$x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{0}$$
where each of the $a_{n}$ are integers, has a rational roots if and only if that root is an integer. It does not give a name for this result.
EDIT: user69810 has pointed out that this is in fact the rational root theorem.

We are then to use this result to prove that the polynomial $$x^{n}-5x+7=0$$
has no rational solutions for $n\ge 2$. My argument was the following:
If there exists a rational root, then it must be an integer.
If there exists an integer root, then $$x^{n}=5x-7$$
for some integers $x$ and $n\ge 2$. Then the LHS is divisible by $x$, meaning that $7$ must be divisible by $x$. Therefore $x \in \{-7,-1,1,7\}$. Checking each of these shows that there is no rational root.

Is this solution correct? It isn't the one in the solutions, but if it's right then I think it's more elegant than theirs.

Comment: The result is called the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Or the Gauss lemma, which immediately gives that $x-a|x^n+\ldots +b\in\mathbb Z[x]$ implies $a|b$.

Comment: Looks fine, but its probably more straightforward to say $x^n-5x=-7 \implies x|x^n-5x \implies x|7$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have identified the possible rational roots correctly and shown that none of them work.  It is a fine application of the rational root theorem.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct. Simpler: Rational Root Test $\,\Rightarrow\,x\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, 7 = 5x\!-\!x^n\,$ is even, contradiction.

Comment: I like this! +1

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not correct, because you are assuming that if $x|5x-7$ then $x|7$. This is not true in general.Think for example to $2+4$. Of course $6|2+4$ but $6$ doesn't divide $2$ nor $4$. What you can say is that $x(x^{n-1}-5)=7$, but $7$ is prime, then you must have $x=1$ and $x^{n-1}-5=7$ or $x=7$ and $x^{n-1}-5=1$. But both are absurd because $x=1$ and $x=7$ doesn't solve the equation. As you can see the result is quite the same, but the procedure is quite different for what you assumed at the beginning. Just a remark, what you called Eisenstein criterion is Gauss Lemma, Eisenstein criterion is about irriducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: since $x|5x$, concluding $x|7$ is absolutely correct.

Comment: No, it's true: $\ x\mid5x,\,5x\!-\!7\,\Rightarrow\,x\mid 5x\!-\!(5x\!-\!7) = 7.\ \ $